# What's dropped before "be it"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

In the following sentence, what is the meaning of 'be it'?

> "Your "ideal self" is the representation of attributes you would like to have ideally, be it related to your future goals, wishes, etc."

Why is it like this?

Comment: Nothing is dropped there. That's a set phrase. For more information, following this link please: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370071

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's archaic. Back in time, people used to invert the subject and the verb and using subjunctive, to express conditionals with formality. Example:

> Were you here with me, I wouldn't be so lonely.
> *If you were here with me, I wouldn't be so lonely.*

In your case, you can interpret it like

> "Your "ideal self" is the representation of attributes you would like to have ideally, **whether it is** related to your future goals, wishes, etc."